# Form not loading if there is no Data and using *ngIf="menuData$

Tags: angular

I am using an Observable on my form to get the data which looks like this on the template side.

```
<form *ngIf="menuData$ | async as menuData; else loading" [formGroup]="form">
```

This works great and i can access all fields in my data from the API. Problem that i am facing now is what to do when I want to use this form to create a new record. In that case there is no menuData$ which means my form never displays the fields. What is the best or correct way to handle this ?

here is the code i use for the observable

```
loadData(docId: string) {
console.log('We are loading Data for Doc : ' + docId);
this.menuParents$ = this.menuService.fetchMenuParents().pipe(
tap(parents => console.log(parents))
)
this.menuData$ = this.menuService.fetchMenuItem(docId).pipe(
tap(menuData => this.form.patchValue(menuData)),
tap(menuData => this.form.controls['DocId'].patchValue(menuData._type + '::' + menuData._id) )
)
this.saveBttn = 'Update'}
```

On the template I just bind the controls to the form which is reactive and is patch after the observable returns data

Comment: Do you use `formData` within the template? If yes then how?

Comment: not sure what you mean with formData. The problem is that menuData is only present when i retrieve a existing record. Since i then call the function to get the data via the observable menuData$. On new Record thats not the case and thats why i am stuck in loading

Comment: Sorry I meant `menuData` - do you use it in the template? How?

Comment: I just updated question to provide some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component TS:

```
@Input() mode = 'add'; // or 'edit'
```

In your template:

```
<form *ngIf="(mode === 'add' || (menuData$ | async as menuData)); else loading" [formGroup]="form">
```

Comment: Thanks,  I actually solved it by subscribing to Observable and then patch the Form once i get Data so the form it self is no longer async. I only use now observables to get data for my dropdowns